# FOSUserBundle + JMSSerializerBundle + exposing extra fields

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I have an issue when serializing a `User` instance with one additional field `$name`, which extends the base User from FOSUserBundle:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity\User;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * User
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Set name
     * @param string $name
     * @return User
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

To simplify, I need to expose only `$salt` field from User entity using `JMSSerializerBundle`

```
#AppBundle\Resources\config\serializer\Model.User.yml
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
    exclusion_policy: all
    properties:
        salt:
            expose: true
```

Here's the config for it:

```
#app\config\config.yml
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        auto_detection: true
        directories:
            FOSUserBundle:
                namespace_prefix: "FOS\\UserBundle"
                path: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/serializer"
```

**The issue is** that the serializer exposes also `$name` field, which I don't want as I need only to have `$salt` exposed:

```
{
    "salt": "abcdefg",
    "name": "Admin"
}
```

I believe I need to tell the serializer to use a config for my `AppBundle\Entity\User` instead of the base user entity from FOSUserBundle, but I have no clue how to implement it.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved the issue . I have a User.php class that 
inherit from FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser. I need control the serialization from both my **BaseUser** class and my **User** class.

Solution: you need 2 separated config file to control each class.

*config.yml*

```
#Serializer configuration
    jms_serializer:
        metadata:
            directories:
                AppBundle:
                    path: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/serializer"
                FOSUB:
                    namespace_prefix: "FOS\\UserBundle"
                    path: "%kernel.root_dir%/serializer/FOSUB"
```

*Model.User.yml*

```
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        id:
            expose: true
        username:
            expose: true
        email:
            expose: true
        enabled:
            expose: true
```

*Entity.User.yml*

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        imageAvatar:
            expose: true
        updatedAt:
            expose: true



namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;



/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="usuario")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DietaBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * 
 *
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


   /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $imageAvatar;



    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;
```

> **Clear the cache after each change in the configuration files.**

*cache:clear*

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are using the `exclusion_policy: all` on the parent entity, instead of on the child entity, which still exposing all of it's properties.

you should switch to your bundle in the configuration (`config.yml`) under the jms_seriazlier:directories.

```
any-name:
    namespace_prefix: "My\\FooBundle"
    path: "@MyFooBundle/Resources/config/serializer"
```

now you could use the same configuration to expose only the desired property.

```
#AppBundle\Resources\config\serializer\Entity.User.yml
My\FooBundle\Entity\User:
    exclusion_policy: all
    properties:
        salt:
            expose: true
```

Comment: Dan, thank you for the reply.
The thing is that my `User` entity is stored in `src/AppBundle/Entity/User/User.php`, and no matter where I put my `yml` file (`src/AppBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.User.yml` or `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.User.User.yml`), it doesn't work, it exposes all the fields, looks like the serializer can't find this `yml` config.

Comment: what about the namespace in the yml file?

it should be like: `AppBundle\Entity\User\User:`

Comment: Here is my `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.User.User.yml`

    AppBundle\Entity\User\User:
        exclusion_policy: all
        properties:
            salt:
                expose: true